# How to get list of entities in python wikidata

Tags: python, wikidata

I need to get all the info about some writers in wikidata

For example - https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q39829

**My code**

```
from wikidata.client import Client
client = Client()
entity = client.get('Q39829', load=True)

# Spouse
spouse_prop = client.get('P26')
spouse = entity[spouse_prop]
print('Mother: ', spouse.label)

# Children
child_prop = client.get('P40')
child = entity[child_prop]
print('Children: ', dir(child))
print(child.label)
```

**Problem**

The problem is with the properties with the list of values

For example, he has 3 children
And in the result I have only one name

**Question**

How can I get the list of all children?

Comment: what does P26 or P40 represent?

Comment: [P26 = spouse](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P26) and [P40 = child](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P40).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs for Wikidata](https://wikidata.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wikidata/entity.html#:%7E:text=Although%20it%20implements%20Mapping%5BEntityId%2C%20object%5D%2C%20it%20actually%20is%20multidict.%20See%20also%20getlist()%20method.):

> Although it implements Mapping[EntityId, object], it [`entity`] actually is multidict. See also getlist() method.

Which means you can do:

```py
>>> [c.label for c in entity.getlist(child_prop)]
[m'Joe Hill', m'Owen King', m'Naomi King']
```